# How to install windows service with visual studio express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-services, visual-studio-express

I have successfully created a `Windows Service` in c# in `Visual Studio 2010` on my local machine. I have to deploy it on the server that has only `Visual Studio Express` edition. This means no command prompt available with the VS. How do I install the service this? Should it be through the computer command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need VS to get the service installed, nor does it help in any way.  Windows still provides you with the command prompt of course.  Be sure to start it by right-clicking the shortcut with "Run as Administrator" so you have sufficient rights to modify the registry.  Then type the *full* path of the install command:

```
 cd \where\you\copied\it
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe yourservice.exe
```

Replace "Framework64" with "Framework" if this is a 32-bit machine.  Be sure to get the server admin involved, he probably cares about you making changes to the machine.  Most do anyway.  And he can be helpful of course, including getting the account+password you need at the UAC prompt.

Comment: I followed these steps and in the `dos` window I get:

`The commit phase completed successfully.
The transacted install completed successfully.`

However I do not see the service in the list of services in `services.exe`. I checked in my `Service1.vb` file and the name of the service is `Service1`. However, I do not see it in the installed services list. Any pointers?

Comment: No idea what services.exe does.  Use Control Panel + Administrative Tools + Services to see a list of installed services.

Answer (score 0):

You should make program install himself as a service when run in non-service mode, the most reliable way (to me) to do it is using some P/Invoke, see [`CreateService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).